# appending and prepending Javascript div?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create a div that will only be acknowledged by JS. I want the div placed over my "container" div id tag like so:

`$('<div id="disco">').prependTo('#container');

$('</div>').appendTo('#container');`

This does not seem to work however. I was wondering why, and how best to resolve this.

Comment: use `before` http://api.jquery.com/before/ instead of `prependTo` or what do you mean with `placed over`?

Comment: Basically I want the 'disco div' to blanket over 'div container', like a, well, container. I'm looking at the before(), but it doesn't wrap around my 'div container'.

Comment: so use `.wrap()` instead

Comment: thanks. worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you are trying to wrap a new div arround  your container?
If this is the case, you can use the following (jQuery) code, since you are already using jQuery in your example:

```
$('#container').wrap('<div id="disco"></div>');
```

cfr. http://api.jquery.com/wrap/

Answer (score 1):

Select your `selectors` like `<div id="disco" />` or `<div id="disco"></div>` instead of `<div id="disco">` and select `<div/>` in place of `</div>`

```
$('<div id="disco"></div>').prependTo('#container');
$('<div/>').appendTo('#container');
```

See [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zyB64/)

If you want to **insert disco div before container** then use [insertBefore()](http://api.jquery.com/insertbefore) or [before()](http://api.jquery.com/before) like,

```
$("<div id='disco'></div>").insertBefore("#container");
```

And if you want to `wrap` your `#container` with `disco div` then use [wrap()](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) as Palash and Kristof Feys answered like,

```
$( "#container" ).wrap( "<div id='disco'></div>" );
```

Comment: your "insertBefore" example needs single quotes :)

Comment: @KristofFeys : disagree

Comment: i meant the ones you've changed ... double around div and double around disco won't work. But you've changed them already :D

Answer (score 0):

Since you want the div placed over the `container` div, you can do this using [`.wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/):

```
$( "#container" ).wrap( "<div id='disco'></div>" );
```

Consider the following HTML:

```
<div id="container">Hello</div>
```

The result after using **`wrap`** is a new  wrapped around the matched element:

```
<div id="disco">
   <div id="container">Hello</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
$('#container').wrap('<div id="disco"></div>');
```